# adding new child node

Tags: symfony

I created a Configuration class and I build a tree that defines my configuration in that class, also to create a child node I do like that:

```
->children()
    ->scalarNode('node1')
        ->isRequired()
        ->cannotBeEmpty()->defaultValue('em_profession_label')->end()
        ->arrayNode('node2') 
            ->isRequired()
            ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
            ->useAttributeAsKey('id')
            ->prototype('array')
        .....
```

Now my problem when I need to add a new child node in my yml file so I must repeat the code above again and again, then I'm looking for a solution to do it automatically that when I add a new child node without adding a new code in my configuration class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your call to `prototype()` you can specify what each child node will look like.

```
//...
->arrayNode('nodes')
    ->prototype('array')
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('option_name1')->end()
            ->scalarNode('option_name2')->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end()
//...
```

That means in your YML config file you can define as many nodes as you like as long as they match what you have mapped in your Configuration. For example...

```
nodes:
    node1:
        option_name1: somevalue
        option_name2: someothervalue
    node2:
        option_name1: somevalue
        option_name2: someothervalue
    node3:
        option_name1: somevalue
        option_name2: someothervalue
```